# SSIS: Getting a red X on OLE DB destination step

Tags: ssis

I'm trying to debug an SSIS job on my local desktop and am running into a problem with the last step, which is writing information to a database:
[image]

There are no errors in the output window:
[image]

I have no idea where else to look to find out what the problem is.  Is there another place I should look to figure out what's up?

Comment: The error list isn't the output window.   During debugging look at the top for an "execution result" tab.   Also look in the View menu for an "Output" view.   There will be more detail in either of these.

Comment: If you made it that far, the most likely errors that i have run into are truncation or the table doesn't allow a null. But like everyone else said, look at the progress tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the output window for errors.
you can see a example output window here..
[image]